# How to make jquery mobile listview fade away

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a basic jquery mobile single listview item. I want to make the listview item fade away and be replaced by another listview item when the user clicks on the arrow on the right hand side.

The code i have below is standard listview

```
   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
   </ul>
```

I hope that someone can advise if it is possible, will i have to clear the whole listview using .remove(); and create a new one?

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) ?

Comment: I have tried reomving the UL and the recreating it with new data when the listview item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I updated the code (using newer jQuery Mobile Version, and removing the ready() function from the code. I also added div wrappers instead, in that way hiding or showing them hides both the list and the search bar altogether.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="l1">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
        <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="l2">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="l2">
        <li><a href="#">Second List View</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#l2").hide();
$('#l1').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $("#l1").fadeOut(300,function(){
        $("#l2").show();
    });
});
```

This code looks cleaner and simpler. Good luck!

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/69Xfz/39/

Comment: I'll try this why im back at home and approved your response. On the face of it it looks like it will work, have you got a JSfiddle demo of this working.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works as well - then you don't have to have predefined lists.

Javascript:

```
$(".mylist").on("vclick", function(e){
var item = $(e.target).closest("li");
var newItem = '<li><a href="#">New Item</a></li>';
item.hide(500);
setTimeout(function(e){
    item.remove();
    $(".mylist").append(newItem).listview("refresh");
}, 500);
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/69Xfz/40/